# Append some text to a list of words

Tags: javascript, bash, parsing, text-processing

I have a list of words in a .txt file

```
About
Who
Get
Which
Go
Me
When
Make
```

I need to obtain

```
user:About
user:Who
user:Get
user:Which
user:Go
user:Me
user:When
user:Make
```

Can you suggest me what can I use in order to obtain this? The list is too long to put manually. 
Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need `JavaScript` for this ?

Comment: @RayonDabre because I don't have experience with other languages

Comment: Need to see your implementation..

Comment: @RayonDabre I have a python script that takes data from .txt file. Format for taking the data is "user:(word)". I have the list of words but I need to to add in front of them "user:".

Comment: Since you've tagged with bash, do you have access to awk? If so: awk '{print "user:" $1}' words.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -pi -e 's/^/user:/' a.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
 sh script.sh list


 #!/bin/bash    
    while read line
    do

    #VARIABLES
    file=$line

    echo "user:"$file >> output

    done < $1
```

Hope it helps.
b.